# Make option to allow JavaScript snippet run by default, hide code by default

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

It's 2014. WebSites shouldn't be limited to static text. An answer about physics with an interactive diagram is much more informative than just some formulas and an explanation

Now that we can embed JavaScript how about allowing to be used for diagramming instead of just JavaScript samples. In other words I'd like to be able to use JavaScript to make an interactive diagram that answers a question. That question may have nothing what-so-ever to do with JavaScript but an interactive diagram might make it much easier to understand the answer.

As such it would be a great option to mark it so the JavaScript runs automatically and the snippet doesn't show in the answer since it's irrelevant.

Examples: [Visual sort algorithm diagrams](http://greggman.github.io/doodles/sort.html), [2D Math Diagrams](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-rotation.html), [3D Math Diagrams](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html).

Computers allow so much more than just static text. Let's embrace that on SO

Comment: Making the JS run by default is not only ripe for abuse, but also incredibly annoying for anybody who does _not_ visit the page to view your snippet. Running a snippet should always be a conscious choice.

Comment: If what the snippet draws IS THE ANSWER then no, JS by default is not bad. Plenty of pages have diagrams. Having those diagrams be interactive is a win. All of SO can be abused. That's what moderation is for.

Comment: Perhaps static images or gifs are better?

Comment: Perhaps it's 2014 and we should move out of thousands of years old limitations

Comment: Sure, that's if you can guarantee that the results will be identical to all users. A gif/image has the advantage of not appearing incorrect in any one browser.

Comment: That's no different than bad a answer. If it doesn't work in some browser others will edit the answer

Comment: @gman you've failed to understand my comment. There are other use cases for visiting a question than "I want to see the answer to that question"; e.g. moderation. Also, there might be multiple answers and maybe I'd prefer the one without a fancy diagram. And no, most of SO can't be abused to crash your browser tab - stack snippets can.

Answer (score 13):

You can already hide a snippet by default. The checkbox says:

> Hide snippet by default (you should include the relevant code above
>   the snippet)

[image]

Running JavaScript by default, however, sounds like a bad idea. It's bad UX because:

- All answers can have stack snippets. Imagine running all of them at the same time, it would not be pretty.
- If it has unwanted side effects, such as alerts, this would be annoying. The user would have to disable the snippet (not sure if this is possible) everytime they enter a page. They might get frustrated and block the javascript, meaning your diagram is rendered useless.
- Something that runs automatically shouldn't. Just think of all the advertisements that play music and you have no idea where it comes from. The user should have the power to run it if they want to.

To address the physics part of the question, I think that this has some potential issues, although I'm not a JavaScript or physics expert:

- Portability. Your code could easily become hacky or a mess simply to ensure that it runs correctly on all browsers. It would distract from the core algorithm or theory.
- You then mention that it could be edited by other users, which is true, except something like a physics simulation is not trivial and requires a higher degree of knowledge/expertise. If no one knows how to fix your code, it could remain broken.
- On top of portability, what if someone is running a 5 year old crappy laptop? How would you be able to distinguish their laptop simply lagging from a simulation that's deliberately running an incorrect algorithm? The only way to show what you really want to show is...

using a static image or GIF. It's less resource intensive and can't possibly be rendered incorrectly (or show incorrect results) to other users. If you want to let the user interact with it, either give reproducible steps (code, program used, platform, and so on) and possibly link to a website containing the demo. Of course, this is bad due to link rot, so a GIF will do appropriately.

---

Barring everything above, there's nothing wrong with having an interactive JavaScript snippet.